# How to test real $http data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, testing, karma-runner, protractor

I would like to test real $http response (not using $httpBackend) and compare with my `mock service` but I still don't know what is the best practice. These are problem description and my propose solution:

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

1. I am creating an full Angular app and API server.
2. Sometime, API development is slower than front-end development. So, I created a `mock service` that inject `$httpBackendProvider` and return `mock data` right before the request is actually sent to server. This module doesn't use `$interceptor`. I think it is deeper than `$interceptor` technique. It works very well.
3. I keep in mind about testing, so I followed `karma` and `protractor`. Both `mock service` and `real api` work pretty well with `protractor` testing.
4. The `PROBLEM` begin when the API design changes. The `protractor` with `real api` is going to fail but the `protractor` with `mock service` is still success.
5. So, in order to make determine which API is wrong, I need to write a comparing script between `real api` and `mock service`.

PROPOSE SOLUTION

Using protractor testing and creating a simple web server like `DEV HTTP CLIENT Chrome addon`.

I would like to hear more from you guys. Thanks!

Comment: I just successful implement my propose solution. Looking for your thought.

Answer (score 2):

You should test your api service first. When you serverside tests break (due to an api change) you should update that test case as well as the clientside test cases as well.

Make sure that you have a solution for API versioning, which is critical after your app has been publicly deployed.

Answer (score 1):

As for development purposes I love to use the [apiary.io](http://apiary.io) service.
This provides you a functional API mockup + full documentation so you can delegate the API to someone else (my choice ;)